# SemaphoreSlim not working under extreme conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, locking, semaphore

We are developing an application using .NET 4.5.1 and implemented my own "async lock" using `SemaphoreSlim` in the background. To lock we use the following method:

```
public async Task<IDisposable> LockAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    await SyncRoot.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return this;
}
```

Where the `SyncRoot` is the `new SemaphoreSlim(1)` instance.

This seems to work fine "in production", but it fails with the following unit-test:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Run<Task>(async () =>
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counterAtomicBegin);
        using (await alock.LockAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            counterLocked += 1;
        }
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counterAtomicEnd);
    });
}
```

There the `counterLocked` and `counterAtomicBegin` are not equal at the end (at 100k tasks they are ~1k off).

**Am I doing something wrong or is this a problem of `SemaphoreSlim`?**

UPDATE: Remove nested logic as recommended and text adapted.
See the following code (can be executed in LINQPad) to test it out: http://pastebin.com/WXecZxqu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.

Asynchronous locks are not thread-affine, so the entire concept of a *thread* holding a lock is incorrect. Rather, a certain section of *code* holds the lock, and parts of that code may execute on different threads.

In my opinion, [recursive locks are a bad idea](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/recursive-re-entrant-locks.html) (link is to my blog post that goes into details). It is theoretically possible to write a recursive asynchronous lock (the only implementation I know of is [part of the test suite for my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Unit%20Tests/AdvancedExamples/RecursiveAsyncLockExample.cs)), but it would only work on .NET 4.5 full framework, and I still think it would be a bad idea.

Comment: So your recommendation is to use normal `lock` statements even in `async` methods or just throw out the "nested locks" (this is not a requirement just a "nice-to-have")?

Comment: I recommend you just remove the "nested locks" and use `SemaphoreSlim`'s `WaitAsync`/`Release`. I do like the idea of having an `IDisposable` wrapper, so I'd keep that in.

Comment: Your `Dispose` method should just call `Release` once.

Comment: Sorry, does not help...
Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: There is also a problem in your test: `Task.Run<Task>` should be `Task.Run`. Monitor will certainly not help in this scenario since it is thread-affine.